# Rspec - Instance variable assigned with 'let' overridden in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm testing a page that loads a random sample of 'members' to display. The rails controller sets them as `@members`. In my test I'm trying to replace this variable with an array of a single hard-coded member hash:

```
require "spec_helper"
describe "the page", type: :feature, js: true do

  let!(:members) do
    [{ name: "Super Grover", title: "Hero" }]
  end

  before do
    visit "/the_page"
    p members
    expect(page).to have_content "some content"
  end

  it ... etc...
end
```

This is a feature test, so Capybara opens up the page and gets clicky. I've added a print in the test (`p members`) and one in the rails view (`p @members`). The rails view shows the value created in the controller (array of random sample), but the test shows the value I've assigned with `let`.

My goal is to have the mocked values appear on the page, not what my controller actually sends my view. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: I think functional tests run outside the boundary of this test data.

Comment: I think Capybara with `js: true` spawns a process that has its own scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is calling the controller and the controller is fetching @members from somewhere ( a model perhaps?), it’s not using your assigned value. You need to tell it to use your value rather than whatever it would get naturally, this is done using a stub. This also needs to happen before the page is called.

```
let!(:members) do
    [{ name: "Super Grover", title: "Hero" }]
end

 it 'does things' do
   allow(Member).to receive(:all).and_return(members)
    visit "/the_page"
     expect(page).to have_content "Super Grover”
     expect(page).to have_content "Hero"
  end
```

Note: if you’re not calling `Member.all` then you need to replace `:all` with whatever you are calling.

Alternatively, if your members are called by a controller method, such as “get_random_members” you can do this instead:

```
  allow_any_instance_of(MembersController).to receive(:get_random_members).and_return(members)
```

Comment: Nailed it! Yes my controller action was calling a method `featured_members` to get `members`. Added `allow_any_instance_of(MyParticularController).to receive(:featured_members).and_return(members)` on the line before `visit "/the_page"` and my view loaded up the mocked `members` just like I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. Also note (for others) that I moved everything out of the `before` block and into the test ad that wouldn’t have been helping.